# Is the resolvent set of the Dirac operator non-empty?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am interested in understanding how is done the resolvent set (actually, I am only interested in proving that it is non-empty) of the free Dirac operator
$$ H_0 = -i\alpha\cdot\nabla + m\beta$$
where $D(H_0) = H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^3;\mathbb{C}^4)$. I am also interested in what happens to the resolvent set of the pertubated operator $H_0+ kV$ where $V$ is a potential.

Could anyone hlep or give me some references?

Thank you in advance!